# Replacing UIView's self with another instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, nib

I want to initialize `xib`-files programmatically in Swift, so I created the class `MyView`.

The initialization of the `xib` is declared in the `setup()` method, where `loadNibNamed()` is called. This returns an additional view, which I have to add as a subview to my current/initial view.

I saw in `User Interface Inspector` that behind `MyView` is the initial view, which has of course also own properties. I do not like this behaviour and do not want to modify properties twice. In the end I want to achieve that the instance from the initializer would be replaceable with the instance that has been created by the call of `loadNibNamed()`; figurative something like `self = view`.

I added the code of the initializers and the `setup()` method.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    NSLog("init with NSCoder")
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

init(in frame: CGRect) {
    NSLog("init with CGRect")
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}


private func setup() {
    NSLog("setting up")
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! MyView
    addSubview(view)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot substitute one self for another in an initializer. `init` and nib-loading are related, but the relationship runs the opposite way from your proposal: loading the view from the nib will call your `init(coder:)`.

What you need is not an initializer but a *factory*.

Give MyView a *class* method (`class func`) that a client can call to load the nib and return the instance.

```
class func new() -> MyView {
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyView", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! MyView
    return view
}
```

Usage:

```
let v = MyView.new()
```

Comment: A workaround seems to be the only solution; thank you ^^

Comment: I don’t see why it’s a workaround. It’s what you do. `init` and nib-loading are two legitimate ways of creating an instance. They are related, but the relationship runs the opposite way from your proposal: loading the view from the nib will call your `init(coder:)`.

Comment: Added that to my answer.

Comment: I tried to create the instance with `init`. The problem is that the `IBOutlet` properties have the value `nil`. That's why I choose the other way.

Comment: That shows a certain confusion about what a nib is. I’m trying to dispel some of that confusion.